# How to remove whitespaces in django urls?

Tags: django, url, replace

I have a question:

How I do to remove the whitespaces in Django urls, or replace it for dash?, for example:

```
http://...com/removewhitespaces
```

or

```
http://...com/remove-white-spaces
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

built in slugify method does the trick:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, one question, how I add this in the urls.py?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve there? Basically urls.py is a place where you put rules for urls you're going to match, like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example